# withCredentials sshUserPrivateKey in Jenkins failed auth fail

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-keys

I used Jenkinsfile in Linux to do SSH to Windows server,
Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools { nodejs "node" }

  environment {
    HOST = "${IP_ADDRESS}"
  }

  stages {
    stage("Remote SSH") {
      steps {
        script {
          withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'build-server-id-rsa', keyFileVariable: 'key')]) {
            def remote = [name: "${HOST}", host: "${HOST}", user: "jenkins", allowAnyHosts: true, identityFile: key]
            sshCommand remote: remote, sudo: true, command: "npm install"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I kept getting errors about `auth fail`:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session$connect$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy:107)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$_connectInternal_closure1.doCall(ConnectionManager.groovy:85)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$_connectInternal_closure1.doCall(ConnectionManager.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.util.Utility.retry(Utility.groovy:52)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.util.Utility$retry.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy:83)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connect(ConnectionManager.groovy:59)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$connect.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.SessionTask.wetRun(SessionTask.groovy:61)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.SessionTask.call(SessionTask.groovy:48)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service.run(Service.groovy:81)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service$run$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.SSHService.executeCommand(SSHService.groovy:177)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution$CommandCallable.execute(CommandStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHMasterToSlaveCallable.call(SSHMasterToSlaveCallable.java:32)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:47)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution.run(CommandStep.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SSHStepExecution.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Update 1. include the top of the jenkins job execution page:

```
Started by user Admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Tool Install)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Remote SSH)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
```

Answer (score 1):

Check first if that same SSH session is possible by doing a regular ssh manually from that same Linux server to the same Windows server, using the account which is running Jenkins.

```
ssh -Tv remoteUser@remoteServer
```

Make sure, for testing, that your private key does not have a passphrase, in order to check if this is an ssh agent issue or not.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I didn't use passphrase and the SSH already work from the terminal, however it fails in Jenkins only when using ssh-pipeline-steps plugin.

The SSH works when we do `sh "ssh -Tv user@server"` in Jenkins.

Comment: @DarrylRN Then may be it works on the terminal, in the Jenkins master, but fails when executed on the Jenkins agent: is the connection executed on the same server or on a different agent?

Comment: I'm still not sure about that, how to debug the agent? because this plugin doesn't show any debug message like the SSH did. I just got the error auth fail without any explanation on which part it fails.

The connection was executed on the same server, but I'm not sure about the agent.

Comment: I tried to use `agent: true` inside the remote object, and this is the error message:
`com.jcraft.jsch.agentproxy.AgentProxyException: connector is not available: `, how can I resolve this?

Comment: @DarrylRN The idea is to not use ssh-agent, and to use a key without passphrase: that way, no need for an agent.

Comment: then the default is already correct, `agent: false` but got the `auth fail` and how to debug which part I failed?

Comment: @DarrylRN By testing the ssh call on the Jenkins agent where the ssh call was made: check your Jenkinsjob execution page: it should say at the top which agent was used (assuming again that you have separate servers acting as agent, in addition of your main Jenkins)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230925/discussion-between-darryl-rn-and-vonc).